# UnauthorizedAccessException downloading a file

Tags: c#, windows, web

I'm attempting to download a file when I click a button, but `UnauthorizedAccessException` is thrown and access to `C:\User\...` is denied.

```cs
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    WebClient Client = new WebClient();
    string Download = "http://...";
    string Location = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + @"\Zentrix\Update";
    Directory.GetAccessControl(Location);
    Client.DownloadFile(Download, Location);
    if (!Directory.Exists(Location))
    {
        DirectoryInfo Folder = Directory.CreateDirectory(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + @"\Zentrix");
    }
    this.Close();
}
```

Comment: The error is pretty self explanatory.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.  To make it easier to help you, 
1. Please use indentation in your code examples so they are easier to read.
2. What is your question?
3. I think the problem you are having is that you do not have rights (or your webserver does not have rights) to edit the folder you are targeting.

Comment: The URI formed by combining BaseAddress and address is invalid.
-or-
filename is null or Empty.
-or-
The file does not exist.
-or- An error occurred while downloading data.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to download the file before you create the directory.

Comment: 1. The program don't get acces to a folder on my pc and I gave everyone on my pc rights/perms for this folder